# Close a bookmarklet from inside it

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm creating a bookmarklet that performs a function similar to Amazon's add anything to your wishlist bookmarklet (http://www.amazon.com/wishlist/get-button). I'm trying to make a cancel button, but I can't seem to get it to work.

How can I make a cancel button that will display  *inside*  the iframe of the bookmarklet, and that will close the iframe?

I've tried using:`window.close` from inside the iframe to do it, but that didn't work. I've also tried using `parent.document.body.removeChild(parent.document.getElementById('iframe'))`, but I get cross domain permissions issues. Any ideas?

Comment: If my answer was a correct solution to your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the iframe in an div. Put the cancel button inside the div, but outside the iframe so that the cancel button is actually in the parent page. This avoids the cross origin problem.

There are ways to work around cross origin problems, but this is by far the simplest solution to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to tell a function in the parent window to close it.

Answer (score 0):

### If you can modify the parent page

Can you modify the parent page (the page in which is contained the frame)? If you can you can do:

```js
function remove()
{
  document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('myIframe'));
  document.write("Frame removed")
}
```

```html
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://stacksnippets.net/js"></iframe>
<br/>
<span onclick="remove()" >Click me to remove the frame from the page</span>
```

In place of the **span** element you can use whatever element you like, for instance a button.

You can also prepare both pages and make them to comunicate with **postMessage**, with each other with a logic similar to this:

Into the iframe page put a javascript like:

```
parent.postMessage('close me', '*')
```

Maybe you wish to wrap the code above into a function to run by a button click event.

Into the parent page put a javascript similar to the following:

```
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) =>
    {
        if(event.data == 'close me')
        {
             yourCloseIframeFunction();
        }
     }, false);
```

Maybe you need to make adaptations to be able to execute it in your pages.

### If you cannot modify the parent page because it is not yours

You cannot remove an element from it by running a javascript from a nested iframe that is yours because of cross origin policy.
But from your page that is shown into the iframe shown into the page that is not yours, you can prevent showing your content by making the browser navigate elsewhere, for instance a blank or not existing page, for example:

```js
if (window.top != window.self)
{
  window.location.href = 'nopage.html';
}
```

```html
my content of the iframed page will not show<br/>
my content of the iframed page will not show<br/>
my content of the iframed page will not show<br/>
my content of the iframed page will not show<br/>
my content of the iframed page will not show<br/>
my content of the iframed page will not show<br/>
```

If you wish you can also empty it automaticly like this:

```js
if (window.self != window.top)
{
  document.body.innerText = 'This page cannot be seen from your nested iframes! Sorry';
}
```

```html
The content of you page<br/>
The content of you page<br/>
The content of you page<br/>
...<br/>
<button onclick="hide()">Don't show page content</button>
```

or just by emptying the iframed page content itself on button click.

Try such a solution just by putting this code into the iframed page:

```js
function removeContent()
{
  document.body.innerText = '';
}
```

```html
The content of you page<br/>
The content of you page<br/>
The content of you page<br/>
...<br/>
<button onclick="removeContent()">Don't show page content</button>
```